# How to change URLs in a Site developed using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a website being developed using Laravel 4 by a freelance dev. While the developer has developed the site with some standard URL's for each page, I want to be able to change the words in URL to suite each of my target markets.
For example, developer made URL of one page: www.site.com/public/city/vehicles

Later, i want to be able to change to www.site.com/Rome/Cars or www.site.com/Sydney/bikes

However the developer says it wont be possible later on to change URLs as this is limitation in Laravel. Can anyone please shed some light on this and how to do this?

Comment: well am not so technically inclined, so i will use your suggestion to brainstorm with my dev

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "/public/" from your Laravel 4 website path by editing your Apache2 configuration files.

This file can be in different places (depending on your server setup), but it should be easily findable. E.g. for AWS EC2 (Ubuntu 14.04) it's `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

You want to place this snippet within that configuration file:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/YOUR_PATH/public
<Directory "/var/www/YOUR_PATH/public">
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
```

Remember to call `service apache2 restart` so your server recognizes and serves this update.

Also, depending on how your developer built your website, you might need to update your [Laravel routing file](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) too.

For reference it should look something like this (app/Http/routes.php):
`Route::get('ajax/support/{city}/{vehicle}', 'MyController@MyMethod');`

Then you'd have a matching method like so (app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php):

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
   public function MyMethod(Request $request, $city, $vehicle)
   {
        // You can access $city and $vehicle here.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it is not possible ?? URL can me made dynamic if you want . Using route as

```
Route::get('/city/{slug}/{slug}',array('as'=>'city.vehciles','uses'=>'yourcontroller@yourmethod'));
```

This will output :

```
       www.site.com/city/Rome/Cars
     //if public folder is removed from url .
//Here `Rome` and `cars` are dynamic and the value comes as per the slug value from database.
```

In the above route `slug` are the thing that can me made dynamic . Just keep some place to add slug while adding vehicle in your dashboard from where you add vehicles.

Also, if you want to explore more then please see this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) .

Hope you get it .